# Object security dynamic setting

Tags: authorization, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I currently have a requirement to implement security on Document objects (non-existing, yet to be added) based on a property of type String/list in which based on the value chosen, the security of the object should change (security is role based). Please note that once the document is created this security-specifier property does not change

I had two approaches in mind. The first approach is that I Create a custom event handler to be triggered on create event, in the event handler, I instantiate a pre-created security policy and apply it to the object.

The second approach is using security proxy objects, so that each Role/ACL is represented by an object, and through the event handler I would assign this security proxy to the document object

My question is, does filenet content foundation 5.2.1 provide any out of the box functionality that covers this without customization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-of-the-box facility to enforce security based on some property value is [Markings](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.security.doc/p8psa057.htm). You should carefully study the documentation as there is some specifics and limitations to their use. For example, one cannot have markings on a property with choice list.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I did not include it in my list of options, plus, markings have a recommended upper limit of 100 marking which would not be suitable in my case.

Comment: I find myself actually more in favor of using the OVL rather than the security policy approach, not sure however which one will have a better performance foorprint

Comment: @WiredCoder You should probably reformulate your question then. You were asking whether there is an out-of-the-box facility. There is.

Comment: I meant a way other than Markings (plus markings will not solve the issue as markings are added not chosen which is my case). but I after searching probably it is the closest OOTB feature to my problem.